# Typescript: How to convert a string to a type

Tags: typescript, types, casting, custom-events

I am creating a bunch of web components and each of them can emit custom events.  As an example here are two simple examples:

```
//MyButton
emits 'myButtonPressed' and detail of this type:
interface ButtonDetailType {
  id: string;
}

//MySlider
emits 'mySliderChanging' and details of this type:
interface SliderChangingDetailType {
  id: string;
  value: number;
}
emits 'mySliderChanged' and details of this type:
interface SliderChangedDetailType {
  id: string;
  oldValue: number;
  newValue: number;
}
```

To listen to the components I have code that looks like:

```
buttonEl.addEventListener( 'myButtonPressed', ( event : CustomEvent ) => {
  const detail = event.detail as ButtonDetailType;
  //now i have access to detail.id
} );

sliderEl.addEventListener( 'mySliderChanging', ( event : CustomEvent ) => {
  const detail = event.detail as SliderChangingDetailType;
  //now i have access to detail.id, detail.value
} );
```

As I'm making more components, I'm having difficulty remembering all the custom event names that each component can emit, or the detailType that each event generates.

To solve this problem I was hoping to create an object that contains all the information like this:

```
EVENTS = {
  button: {
    myButtonPressed: 'myButtonPressed',
    detailType: 'ButtonDetailType',
  },
  slider: {
    mySliderChanged': 'mySliderChanged',
    detailTypes: {
     'SliderChangedDetailType',
     'SliderChangingDetailType',
    }
  }
};
```

With that, I now have an easy way to access all the Event names available for each component with auto-complete helping me along the way as I type:

```
buttonEl.addEventListener( EVENTS.button. //autocomplete shows me all event names here! YAY!
sliderEl.addEventListener( EVENTS.slider. //autocomplete here too!
```

The problem that I am having is I don't know how to **convert a string to a type**.  I'd like to be able to type this:

```
buttonEl.addEventListener( EVENTS.button.myButtonPressed, ( event : CustomEvent ) => {
  const detail = event.detail as EVENTS.button.detailType; // <- invalid: EVENTS.button.detailType is a string not a type!
} );
```

Is there a way to convert strings to types in TypeScript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't really convert strings to types without a mapping.  In fact, you really don't want those strings in the first place except for the actual string passed into `addEventListener()` as the `type` parameter.  It seems like what you actually want is something like [namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) or [modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) to organize your types.

For example, using namespaces we can get something similar to your `EVENTS` object, except that instead of referring to just string values, it refers to string values *and* types:

```
namespace EVENTS {
  export namespace button {
    export const myButtonPressed = "myButtonPressed";
    export namespace detailType {
      export interface ButtonDetailType {
        id: string;
      }
    }
  }
  export namespace slider {
    export const mySliderChanged = "mySliderChanged";
    export namespace detailTypes {
      export interface SliderChangingDetailType {
        id: string;
        value: number;
      }
      export interface SliderChangedDetailType {
        id: string;
        oldValue: number;
        newValue: number;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should give you the same autocompletes you saw before, plus ones for the types:

```
buttonEl.addEventListener(EVENTS.button.myButtonPressed, ((event: CustomEvent) => {
  const detail = event.detail as EVENTS.button.detailType.ButtonDetailType;
}) as EventListener);

sliderEl.addEventListener(EVENTS.slider.mySliderChanged, ((event: CustomEvent) => {
  const detail = event.detail as EVENTS.slider.detailTypes.SliderChangedDetailType;
}) as EventListener)
```

It's up to you if you want to change the level of nesting and naming of things since the namespace makes some things redundant (maybe you want `EVENTS.slider.details.SliderChanged` instead of `EVENTS.slider.detailTypes.SliderChangedDetailType`), but the main idea here is the general approach of using namespaces or modules.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: fantastic, this is exactly what I was looking for!