# how to use string value as a type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my code I import an object that also containing type for each property, for example(simplified):

```
const obj= {
  OUTPUT: ["port","number"],
}
```

which means `OUTPUT:{port:number;}`

how can i extract the second constant in the array to represent the type of the first constant in the array?

any help will be very appreciated,thanks in advance.

#### I've already tried:

```
const string2Type = (str: string): string | number | object => {
  const tmp: any = null;
  switch (str) {
    case "number":
      return tmp as number;
    case "string":
      return tmp as string;
    case "object":
      return tmp as object;
  }
};

const obj = {
  OUTPUT: ["port","number"],
};

const OUTPUTtype = string2Type(obj.OUTPUT[1]) 

const OUTPUT = obj.OUTPUT[0] as typeof OUTPUTtype
// but here OUTPUT: string | number | object instead of number... How can i fix this?
```

(of course this wouldn't work because switch case is runtime (in javascript) and typescript is compiled language, but I can't get this to work)

#### similar question:

most close is [Typescript: How to convert a string to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133265/typescript-how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-type) but i don't see how it can solve my specific issue.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771307/typescript-dynamically-create-interface

Comment: `obj.OUTPUT[2]` does not exist, as arrays start with 0. Shouldnt it be `obj.OUTPUT[1]`?

Comment: @EmreKoc yes you are right.
<br/>
@MauriceNino yes it is actually does. Didn't know about `typescript assertions`. i think about how to implement it in these now.

Comment: yes it does.

this question can be marked as duplicate.